# Make last two rows bold of Treeview in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have an excel range loaded in tree view. What i want is to bold the last two rows of the table in tree view. Is it possible? And is it also possible to change color of a particular cell in tree view e.g i want to change the color of cell(3,3) to green.

Please help. Here is my code.

```
# Import the required libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import pandas as pd

# Create an instance of tkinter frame
win = Tk()
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsm', sheet_name = 'Differential Pressure',usecols="A:I",header=47,nrows=11)
# Set the size of the tkinter window
win.geometry("900x350")


# Create an object of Style widget
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

# Add a Treeview widget
my_tree = ttk.Treeview()
my_tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
my_tree["show"] = "headings"
for column in my_tree["column"]:
    my_tree.heading(column,text=column)

df_rows=df.to_numpy().tolist()
for row in df_rows:
    my_tree.insert("","end",values=row)

my_tree.column("#1",anchor=W, stretch=NO, width=70)
my_tree.column("#2",anchor=W, stretch=NO, width=200)
my_tree.column("#3",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=60)
my_tree.column("#4",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=100)
my_tree.column("#5",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=120)
my_tree.column("#6",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=60)
my_tree.column("#7",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=60)
my_tree.column("#8",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=60)
my_tree.column("#9",anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=60)

my_tree.row("#1",st)

my_tree.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is covered in the treeview documentation. It's not clear why you need our help.

Comment: You can change the style of individual row but not individual cell.

Comment: Hi can you please provide me the code on how to change the color of last two rows. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can change style of individual row but not individual cell.

However there is bug on styling foreground and background color of `Treeview` rows after *tk 8.6*, a temporary fix proposed as below:

```py
...
# Create an object of Style widget
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

def fix_map(option):
    return [elm for elm in style.map('Treeview', query_opt=option)
               if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]

style.map('Treeview', foreground=fix_map('foreground'),
                      background=fix_map('background'))
...
```

Now you can create style using `.tag_configure()`:

```py
my_tree.tag_configure('bold', font=('',0,'bold'), foreground='red')
```

Then apply the style to last two rows:

```py
for row in my_tree.get_children()[-2:]:
    my_tree.item(row, tags='bold')
```